# Error to find minimum of last column of pandas DataFrame in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm using `read_csv()` to read data from external .csv file. It's working fine. But whenever I try to find the minimum of the last column of that dataframe using `np.min(...)`, it's giving lots of errors. But it's interesting that the same procedure is working for the rest of the columns that the dataframe has.

I'm attaching the code here.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os

data = pd.read_csv("test_data_v4.csv", sep = ",")

print(data)
```

The output is like below:

```
    LINK_CAPACITY_KBPS  THROUGHPUT_KBPS  HOP_COUNT  PACKET_LOSS  JITTER_MS  \
0                  25             15.0         50         0.25         20   
1                  20             10.5         70         0.45          3   
2                  17             12.0         49         0.75          7   
3                  18             11.0         65         0.30         11   
4                  14             14.0         55         0.50         33   
5                  15              8.0         62         0.25         31   

   RSSI   
0    -30  
1    -11  
2    -26  
3    -39  
4    -25  
5    -65  

np.min(data['RSSI'])
```

Now the error comes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/koushik_k/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1914, in __getitem__
return self._getitem_column(key)
File "/home/koushik_k/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1921, in _getitem_column
return self._get_item_cache(key)
File "/home/koushik_k/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site- 
packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1090, in _get_item_cache
values = self._data.get(item)
File "/home/koushik_k/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site- 
packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3102, in get
loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
File "/home/koushik_k/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site- 
packages/pandas/core/index.py", line 1692, in get_loc
return self._engine.get_loc(_values_from_object(key))
File "pandas/index.pyx", line 137, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
(pandas/index.c:3979)
File "pandas/index.pyx", line 157, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
(pandas/index.c:3843)
File "pandas/hashtable.pyx", line 668, in
pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12265)
File "pandas/hashtable.pyx", line 676, in
pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12216)
KeyError: 'RSSI'
```

Comment: Check `print(data.columns)` -- probably there's whitespace you didn't expect around the name.

Answer (score 0):

Following on DSM's comment, try data.columns = data.columns.str.strip()